# Windows 7 Repair Install

Tags: windows-7, windows, repair-install

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 Black screen of death](https://superuser.com/questions/79421/windows-7-black-screen-of-death)

I am attempting to do a repair install of a Windows 7 Premium (x32). I am attemting to follow this guide:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

However, my windows wont load fully. It loads enough that startup repair wont detect a problem. I get a black screen with the mouse courser after "Starting windows" goes away.

So my question is, how can I do a repair install without loading into windows?

Comment: You will need to provide more information.  It sounds like you might have to simply reinstall Windows.

Comment: In this instance Windows re-install is out of the question. It has to be a repair install.

Comment: You can't: for the symptoms described, see http://superuser.com/questions/79421/windows-7-black-screen-of-death